# Hive on AWS EMR does not work

Tags: hive, amazon-emr

I have a brand new EMR cluster (EMR version 5.16, Hadoop 2.8.4, and Hive 2.3.3). It's connected to the GLU Data Catalog. I can list the tables, describe, and even "select *" successfully. But, once I start a real query that has to run a Tez or MR jobs on YARN, it fails. Even "select count(*) " on a simple, uncompressed text table fails.

The Tez stderr logs suggests a bunch of S3 errors (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request;), but the YARN container logs has lib errors (|lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader|: Could not load native gpl library). Does anybody know whats going on here? This seems like basic stuff on EMR, but doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have permissions setup on the bucket in S3? Do you have a "folder" in that bucket, with the same name as your table, with the datafiles inside?

Comment: Yes. Select * works since it doesn't have to run any jobs, just read the data on S3. Queries that require running Tez or MR jobs on EMR fails. Feels like it can't write files or folder on S3 for output or logs, but I can't nail it down.